# how to remove click anywhere in fragment layout goes to main activity button clicked on that click

Tags: android, click, fragment

When i click anywhere in fragment layout goes to main activity button clicked on the click, how to remove this transparency in fragment.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);
    return view;
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear? Can you elaborate?

Comment: is that sufficient?

Comment: I didn't think that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I face this problem before, try to add this lines to parent layout `fragment_blank`

For example

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true">

    <!--other views-->

</LinearLayout>
```